# Argument must be instance of message in laravel broadcast

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I set up broadcasting I get this error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Events\MessagePosted::__construct() must be
>   an instance of App\Events\Message, instance of App\Message given,
>   called in /var/www/epg/app/Http/Controllers/MessageController.php on
>   line 25 /var/www/epg/app/Events/MessagePosted.php#37

I trigger event like this from my controller

`broadcast(new MessagePosted($message, $user))->toOthers();`

It should broadcast the message and the user to that event

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Message;
use App\Events\MessagePosted;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request) 
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        // Store the new message
        $message = $user->messages()->create([
            'message' => $request->get('message')
        ]);

        // Announce that a new message has been posted
        broadcast(new MessagePosted($message, $user))->toOthers();

        return ['status' => 'OK'];
    }
}
```

I do not understand what is going on since what I have seen people say check you imports but I imported the right classes in the controller.

Comment: Can you post your `MessagePosted` file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `MessagePosted` file is similar to this

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\User; //your model
use App\Message; //your model
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class MessagePosted implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(Message $message, User $user)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name'); // your channel name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were passing `App\Message` into the `MessagePosted` constructor. The error indicates that your `MessagePosted` is accepting `App\Events\Message` instead of `App\Message`. It tends to happens when you forgot to `use App\Message` in your `MessagePosted`, thus it's using the namespace of the `MessagePosted` which is `App\Events` for the `Message`, resulting `App\Events\Message`.

In short, `use App\Message` in your `MessagePosted` class.